# Injecting Named Actors into Play! Test

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I have a web app that uses a custom Akka Actor.

I inject the actor using the @Named annotation, something like this:

```
@Singleton
class Thing @Inject()(@Named("scheduler-actor") schedulerActor: ActorRef) ...
```

I'd like to inject this actor into my tests so that I can send messages to it but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm using the `Injecting` Trait which gives me access to the `inject` function but there doesn't appear to be any alternative `inject` function that would allow me to pass in a name.

Are there any examples floating around on the internet of injecting an actor into a Play! test?

---

**Update 1**

After a little research I've come up with this solution, it feels a little hacky however.

First I installed Akka TestKit.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.22" % Test
```

Then I used `TestActorRef` like this:

```
import actors.SchedulerActor.RefreshDevicesFromCCU
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.testkit.TestActorRef
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll
import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec
import utils.DatabaseSetupTearDown

class SchedulerActorSpec 
  extends PlaySpec
    with GuiceOneAppPerSuite
    with Injecting {

  implicit val system: ActorSystem = inject[ActorSystem]
  val schedulerActor: SchedulerActor = inject[SchedulerActor]
  val schedulerActorRef: ActorRef = TestActorRef(schedulerActor)

  ...
}
```